# Add after a certain number in PHP

Tags: php, math

I have this project that has a set price for a certain amount of hours, I need to add more money to the overall total for each hour after 5.

My script already calculated the time by counting the hours:

Which outputs like, "**15**" or "**9.5**" or "**3.5**" or "**7**" etc.

Let's say that **5** hours is £50, how would I add an additional £15 for every hour over the **5** hour limit.

This includes if a user going over by "**.5**"

*(So **5.5** hours would be £65 and **6** would be £65)*

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract 5 from the number of hours, ceil() / round() the number and multiply by 15?
You ceil() if you want *any* part of an hour to be charged, whereas you round() if you want to charge only if the fraction of the hour is .5 or higher.

```
$hours = 5.5;
$amount = 50 + ceil(max(0,$hours-5)) * 15; # 65
```

Comment: I added a code example, round is probably even better because you can specify a flag how it should be rounded, so it's more flexible for modifications. And it has a precision specifier. http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 0):

I assume that anything belove 5 hours is 50.

```
$price = $val <= 5 ? 50 : (50 + (int) ceil($val-5) * 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, are you looking for something like this:

```
$total = 50;
if($hours > 5) {
   $total += ceil($hours - 5) * 15;
}
```